Cells in phase space in Maxwell-Boltzmann statistical analysis of thermodynamics

Can't the states overlap? For example, for one particle the value of spread of its $p_x$ is 1 unit from $p_x=0.5$ to $p_x=1.5$ whereas, for the other particle, is 1 unit from $p_x=1$ to $p_x=2$. Isn't this possible? If it is possible, then there can be many more states available for particles and the formula must be wrong.

What you are learning is still in the semi-classical regime and so they cannot tell you the full answer. Then, by definition, there is no overlapping. In the quantum version of this, there is a quantum description that makes clear what kind of overlapping (superposition) is allowed and yet it will cause a forbidding of having more than one particle in one state, necessary for this accounting to appear as in experimentally seen.

It looks like they are describing something different than pictured. Using words, they say the the center of the cell is located at ${x,,p}$ while in the picture the node appears to be located at ${x,,p}$. In the verbal description, there is 1 'space' around the point the particle could be. In the pictorial description (which you seem to be following also), there are 4 spaces.
